# codeigniter display database connection information

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a config with multiple DB's and based on the constraints passed to the config a DB is used. With that, I am trying to debug to ensure the right DB is used when I want it to be. So I need to see what DB is being used. I remember once having found this gem that would display that information but did not save it nor do I remember the search terms that lead me to it.

Overall I just want to print out the db host, db name, and connection information so I can make sure its lining up with the plan.

I want to say the command was something like `$this->db()` but that doesn't display anything. So does anyone by chance happen to know? Cause I can't find it in the CI guide either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [get_instance](http://henrypeteralbers.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html) class.

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
echo $CI->db->hostname;
```